# How to use GETDATE() in Oracle to find number of days between Current Date and some specified date?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, getdate, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

Suppose I have a table called `projects` and it has columns as `projectid, startdate and enddate`. The startdate of each project is specified already and the enddate is specified only for projects that are already finished. For ongoing projects, the enddate is `null`.
We have to perform this task :

Find  the  project  ID  and  duration  of  each  project.  If  the  project has not finished,  report  its execution time as of now. [Hint: Getdate() gives current date]

For this I wrote this code,

```
select projectid,
CASE
when enddate is null then GETDATE() - startdate
else enddate - startdate
END
as "duration" from projects;
```

But this is giving me

```
ORA-00904: "GETDATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 113 Column: 27
```

The line 113, column 27 is the position of GETDATE().

So what exactly is the way to use getdate() here?

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL Server? From the error message it looks more like Oracle...

Comment: Oh yes, I am using Oracle. Sorry, I specified the wrong details.

Comment: Answer improved, should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GETDATE()` is a function from TSQL. What you want to use instead is `CURRENT_DATE`. Also, I improved your query a bit by using `COALESCE`.

```
select projectid,
COALESCE(enddate,CURRENT_DATE) - startdate 
as "duration" from projects;
```

You may want to refine the result using `FLOOR()` as well to get exact days.

Comment: I am getting this error : ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 119 Column: 1

Comment: line 119 column 1 is DATEDIFF